# Vertically Center Various Text in Header?

Tags: html, css, navigation, vertical-alignment

This can probably be fixed insanely easy but I'm just having such a hard time at doing it.

So, I want to make both my name and the navigation bar in the header appear at the center vertically. My current code only makes my name be centered, since it is bold and the font-size is bigger.

This is the code:

HTML:

```
  <div id="header">
<ul>
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header-name">
      <li>
        <a href="/index.html">
          <span class="first"><strong>First</strong></span>
          <span class="last"><strong> Last</strong></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#header-wrapper {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

#header ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: orange;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#header .header-name li {
float: left;
}

#header .header-nav li {
float: right;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#header li a {
font-size: 15px;
display: block;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#header .header-name li a {
font-size: 22px;
}



#header ul li a .first {
color: #ccc;
}

#header a {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. A `ul` needs to have an `li` as direct children. Instead, you have `div`s as direct children with nested `li`'s

That said, add `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;` to `#header-wrapper` to center those elements vertically.

```css
#header-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#header .header-name li {
  float: left;
}

#header .header-nav li {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#header li a {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header .header-name li a {
  font-size: 22px;
}

#header ul li a .first {
  color: #ccc;
}

#header a {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<ul>  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header-name">
      <li>
        <a href="/index.html">
          <span class="first"><strong>First</strong></span>
          <span class="last"><strong> Last</strong></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just wondering, what could possibly be the consequences of not having the li as a direct child of the ul? It seems to work just fine, but it probably makes the site slower, etc. Also, how could I possibly create a header-wrapper if I can't have any divs in between?

Comment: @Sidexx it's invalid HTML. It isn't semantic. If a screen reader hit the `ul` it would expect to read a "list" of things separated by `li` elements and you don't have that. It's just invalid. Browsers usually figure it out and display things correctly, but the markup is wrong and there  might be unexpected consequences, like the screen reader example.

Comment: @Sidexx I would structure it something like this instead https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWprLZ